# Bootstrap 4 popover with fade effect?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

is there example of how to produce nice fade effect on Bootstrap 4.21 popover, like it exists on Modal component?
I try to add "fade" class to popover but it does not helped.
Basically, I need that popover has a focus and background is grayed, like it works on Modal dialogs.
Thank you.

Comment: Might want to try to at least include code. Here's the documentation: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/ Should be a fade effect in there.

Comment: Try this  `$('.target').popover({title: "Header", content: "content", animation: true});` using jQuery.

Comment: @Ishaan thanks, but it does not work.

Comment: Try to add a `delay: 1000` with the object. However a refernce is [here](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_popover.asp)

Comment: make image of your need and we help on that

Comment: @brooksrelyt fade does not work, there is no special code, it is simple popover but I already try to add fade class - it does not work. Thank you.

Comment: @Nisharg Shah image is here: https://imgur.com/a/vRYo3tE displayed is gray animated (fade) background when Modal example is executed. I need same when popover is executed. Thank you.

Comment: @Ishaan it does not work even with delay..

Comment: @all, here is simple example: https://codepen.io/krosoftware/pen/PVzOWz - question is - how to get nice faded gray background (modal) when popover is opened? thank you.

Comment: @user2666909 got it, wait let me help

Comment: @NishargShah great, thanks a lot.

Comment: see my answer, bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply follow the rule of model, you can see in this [link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/components/modal/) by doing inspect element.

**Explanation**

when popover shown, i add some CSS on one `div` element, that doing gray color in whole `body` and after popover hides, i revert all changes.

i added `position absolute` and `z index` on button when click because its highlight button and make it clickable.

```js
$('#mypop').popover();

$('#mypop').on('show.bs.popover', function () {
  $('.example').addClass('popoverCSS');
  $(this).addClass('popoverBtnCSS');
});
$('#mypop').on('hide.bs.popover', function () {
  $('.example').removeClass('popoverCSS');
  $(this).removeClass('popoverBtnCSS');
});
```

```css
.popoverCSS {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.popoverBtnCSS {
  position: absolute;  /* you can use position: fixed also */
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<button type="button" id="mypop" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover title" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?">Click to toggle popover </button>
<div class="example"></div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

if you found any problem related to this answer, comment below.

Answer (score 0):

A MUCH easier way to do this without requiring any custom CSS is to simply add the following JavaScript that inserts/removes the 'modal-backdrop' element on show/hide of the popover.

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').on('show.bs.popover', function () {
    $("body").append("<div class='modal-backdrop fade show'></div>")
});
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').on('hide.bs.popover', function () {
    $(".modal-backdrop").remove();
});
```